# Scanf of multiple string data in 1D array

Tags: arrays, c

I'm confused about how to store multiple string data in 1D array. I want to store the time in 1D String Array.

[image: Image of data to be stored in different arrays]

I tried putting the scanf of time in the for loop but it shows no output. So I tried putting it outside the for loop just to see the output.

Below is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int 
main() {
     int i, j, row, col;
     col = 3;
     row = 4;
     char time[6];
     float amtArr[row];
     float dtArr[col][row];

     //Store time in 1D String Array
     scanf("%s", time);
     for(i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    
     }

     //Store data1, data2, data3 in 2D Float Array
     for(i = 0; i < col; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < row; j++) {
           scanf("%f", &dtArr[i][j]);
        }
     }

     //Store amt in 1D Float Array
     for(i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        scanf("%f", &amtArr[i]);
     }

     //Print time
     printf("\n%s\t", time);
     for(i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    
     }

     //Print data1, data2, data3
    for(i = 0; i < col; i++) {
       for(j = 0; j < row; j++) {
          printf("%.1f \t", dtArr[i][j]);
       }
       printf("\n");
    }

    for(i = 0; i < row; i++) {
       printf("%.1f \t", amtArr[i]);
    }

    return 0; }
```

Output of no for loop for 1D array of time

[image: Result of printing]

Comment: `char time[5];` is too short to store 5-character strings like `11:50` because there are no room to store the terminating null-character. Allocate enough elements and set the maximum number of characters to read like `%4s` to avoid buffer overrun.

Comment: Two tips for writing a program that does input like this: (1) *Always* print prompts, like `printf("enter the time:\n")`, and (2) *always* check `scanf`'s return value, to make sure you got the value(s) you expect.  There are 17 different little things that can and will go wrong when you use `scanf` for input, and you'll drown in them if you're not careful.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! 

As for the input I was using a text file and input-output redirection so I didn't put any prompt about asking the time.

The problem I still have is the for loop for printing and storing the time.

Comment: `char time[5];` means only 5 characters, it does not mean 5 strings. eg, `char time[5] = {"11:50"}` not `char time[5] = {"11:50","01:20","03:00","22:00","11:11"}`

Comment: @sittsering `char time[6] = "11:50"`, or the much preferred `char time[] = "11:50"`.  But under no conditions should you write `char time[5] = "11:50";`, and if you do you should pay attention to the compiler warning.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be attempting to read the file multiple times without rewinding.  Just do something like:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

struct row {
        char time[6];
        double data[3];
        double amt;
};

int
main(void)
{
        char *expect[] = {"Time", "Data1", "Data2", "Data3", "Amt"};
        struct row r[50];
        struct row *t = r;
        for( unsigned i = 0; i < sizeof expect / sizeof *expect; i++ ){
                char buf[128];
                if( 1 != scanf("%127s", buf) || strcmp(buf, expect[i]) ){
                        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input\n");
                        return 1;
                }
        }
        while( 5 == scanf("%5s %lf %lf %lf %lf",
                t->time, &t->data[0], &t->data[1], &t->data[2], &t->amt)
                && t < r + sizeof r / sizeof *r )
        {
                t += 1;
        }
        for( struct row *i = r; i < t; i++ ){
                printf("%lf\n", i->data[0]);
        }
        return 0;
}
```